# Efficient way to append JSON-object without parse it

Tags: json, node.js, optimization

I wrote a small script listening on an udp-port and stores all incoming messages (one JSON object) inside a single file. The empty file contains an array in JSON format.
I'm looking for an efficient way to store all (concurrently) incoming messages from multiple clients inside this single file.
The files size can be multiple hundred of megabytes large. Parsing the file and appending the new object wouldn't be efficient as needed.

Do you have an approach?

**EDIT**
My solution, based on @t-j-crowder approach:

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var fs = require("fs");
var udp_server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

var udp_server_port = 5000

udp_server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {

      var json_part = "{\"message\": " + msg + "}";

        fs.open('./data/stats.json','r+',function(err,fd){
            if(err) throw err

            fs.fstat(fd,function(err,stats){
                if(err) throw err               

                if(stats.size>2){
                    json_part = new Buffer(','+json_part+']','utf-8');
                    var pos = parseInt(stats.size)-1;
                }else{
                    json_part = new Buffer('['+json_part+']','utf-8');
                    var pos = 0;
                }

                fs.write(fd,json_part, 0, json_part.length, pos, function(err,written,buffer){
                    if(err) throw err
                    fs.close(fd,function(){
                    });
                });

            });

        });

});

udp_server.bind(udp_server_port);
```

Regards, Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, you'll need to:

1. Open the file using a seekable, writable stream.
2. Seek to the end of it.
3. Back up one character (over the closing `]` of the array).
4. Write out a comma (if this isn't the first entry) and the JSON of your new entry.
5. Write a closing `]`.
6. Close the file.

Looking at the NodeJS docs, it looks like Steps 2-4 (and arguably 5) are done all together, using the `position` argument of [`fs.write`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback). (Be sure you open the file using `r+`, not one of the "append" modes.)

Comment: looks simple and good: thanks! Nodejs takes care of concurrent write access to a single file (that's blocked) by itself or do i have to manage this cases?

Comment: @arbyter: NodeJS *can't* assure atomic access to the file (because other processes could try to write to it) and as far as I know, by default, doesn't try. I haven't done it with the Node API, but in generaly you can ask the file system to deny write access (or even read access) to the file while you have it open with appropriate flags. You'll probably have to research how to do that with Node's API (I'm not immediately seeing the options I'm thinking of in the `fs.open` docs.)

Comment: @arbyter:  My suggestion is to use database instead of flat file on filesystem.  Then you can just insert a message to the database when there is one.  MongoDb is good for storing json objects.  This way you can search, sort, get range of messages, and etc.

Comment: @ben: One criteria is a minimal system footprint so a database is out of the question.